Regex to Match Numeric String But NOT all Zeroes between Delimiters
I have a Regex match string that looks like this:
^\d{5,6}[_\.\-]\d{1,3}[_\.\-]\d{1,2}[_\.\-]\d{1,3}$

This is to make sure the format of the string is correct. Obviously it is looking for numbers separated by specific delimiters so that it will match something like this:
240967.004.03.857 (the period delimiters can also be either _ or -).
This is working fine. However, I need to make sure that the numbers between the delimiters are not all zeroes.  Zeroes can be in the numbers, just not all of the digits in the delimited parts.
What's the best way to do this?

^(?!0+[_.\-])\d{5,6}[_.\-](?!0+[_.\-])\d{1,3}[_.\-](?!0+[_.\-])\d{1,2}[_.\-](?!0+$)\d{1,3}$

The question had been closed on the ground that it is a duplicate of this earlier question. I voted to reopen because the current question has additional requirements over the earlier one. The earlier question has several elements, only one of which is relevant to the current question, that the entire string not be all zeroes.

Thank you @Wiktor, This works very well, providing the delimiters can "mix-n-match" (my initial instructions did not specify one way or the other).  I will use either the excellent match below (by @Cary) or yours depending on getting that answer.  Thanks to you both!

In addition to the stated requirements I assume that the same period separator of strings of digits ('_', '.' or '-') must be used throughout. '240967.004-03.857', for example, would be invalid. With this assumption the string is valid if and only if it matches the following regular expression (provided the regex engine supports negative lookaheads, which many do).
^          # match the beginning of the string
(?!        # begin a negative lookahead
  .*       # match >= 0 chars other than line terminators
  \b0+\b   # match one or more zeros with word boundaries fore and aft
)          # end negative lookahead
\d{5,6}    # match 5-6 digits
([_.-])    # match one of the characters in the character class
           # (the 'separator') and save it to capture group 1
\d{1,3}\1  # match 1-3 digits followed by the separator
\d{1,2}\1  # match 1-2 digits followed by the separator
\d{1,3}$   # match 1-3 digits at end of the string

I've written this expression in extended mode (a.k.a. free-spacing mode) to make it self-documenting.
The negative lookahead (?!.*\b0+\b), together with other elements of the expression, ensures there is no string of zeroes between successive separators, between the beginning of the string and the first separator and between the last separator and the end of the string.
Demo

As a sidenote, when I see something like this, I would seriously consider NOT using a regex and just parse it manually...

@Christian, is your reason because of the complexity or inefficiency?  This one-line Regex seems to be a good suggestion.

@linebam59: most likely, complexity AND inefficiency AND hiding the desired goad behind unreadable mumbo-jumbo. If you cannot write it yourself now, how do you expect that someone else (or even you) will understand it 6 months from now? If it is just a homework, go ahead, no problem. But if needs to be maintained, better to find another way. Congrats to Cary Swoveland for being able to create this regex.

@bobblebubble, thank you for the suggested improvement. I've incorporated it in my answer.
